# linqでグループごとに連番をふりたい

Tags: c#, linq

実現したいことはデータの塊ごとに連番を表示したいです。

のような形で一つの注文に対して紐づいた連番を取得したい場合、linqだとどのようにしたら値を取得できますか？
linqについて全く理解ができていないのでわからないのですが、複数selectをすることができるものなのですか?
groupbyをするときはgroupbyのみしかかくことができないものなのでしょうか？
下記のinnnerjoin以降のコードを書いたときは(from句)を書いたものにgroupbyを追記するときはどのような形にすればいいのでしょうか？。
作成コード

```cs
 List<Oracle> oracle = createOracleList();
            List<Csv> csv = createCsvList();
            int i++;
            var innnerjoin = from c in csv
                             join o in oracle
                             
                                 select new  ResultDT
                                 {
                                     
                                     名前 = c.Name,
                                     番号= 1
                                 };
```

Comment: 連番を振る話からズレてきていると思います。尋ねたいことを整理して新規質問として投稿してください。

Comment: かしこまりました。＠sayuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クエリ構文では使えませんが、メソッド構文であればインデックス付きの[`Select`メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__)や[`SelectMany`メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___)が用意されています。ですので、そもそも要素数を数える行為が適切か考慮が必要です。

```
var query = enumerables
   .GroupBy(x => x.name, (x, i) => new { x.name, no = i + 1, x.item })
   .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: 要素数を数えるという表現は間違っていたでしょうか？文章力がなくすみません。

Comment: 「要素数を数える」は亀レオンさんの考えた手段であり、真の目的は連番をふることかと。手段でなく求めていることを直接尋ねるべきでした。

Comment: なるほど、連番をふるという表現のほうが確かにわかりやすいですね。質問修正致します。

Comment: 追加で質問なのですが、上記の回答いただいたものをコードに差し込むにあたって元々書いていたコードは消す必要はございますか？　理由　x.nameが出てこないため

Comment: @亀レオン  それは今回の質問の範囲外では？ 入力データについて言及されていない以上、nameとitemが存在する前提でnoを生成する部分を尋ねたんですよね？

Comment: nameとitemは存在するのですが、var query = enumerablesのenumerablesがないというメッセージが出たのでsは必要ないのかと思い書き直したところ new { x.name, no = i + 1, x.item });の部分でx.でnameが出てこない状況になります。別で質問したほうがよろしいでしょうか？ここらへんが全くわからないのでご教授願いたいです。

Comment: `var enumerables = from c in csv join o in oracle on c.code equals o.code select new ResultDT { name = c.name, item = o.item }` くらいになるのでは？ `csv` や `oracle`、`ResultDT`について何の説明もないので知らんけど。